# Alembic animation not rendering in Octane

Tags: rendering, alembic, octane-render-engine

does anyone know why my animated alembic mesh (vertexanimation) shows correctly in the viewport but is not rendered out. I am using Octane with the latest blenderversion.

Rendering in Cycles (GPU) works like expected... seems to be an octane limitation :-(

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue:
under the Object Properties of the alembic File, the *"Object Type"* under the *Octane Settings* needs to be set to **Reshapable Proxy**